# Why does merely writing SeriesData[] with zeros give an error, even if it is never called?

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Why does the code

```
Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1]]
```

give me the following error?

```
First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.
```

First, why in the world is `SeriesData` even evaluated inside the `Function`?

Second, what exactly is the error? Can't a series be zero?

Comment: Have you tried to click on the **>>** sign?

Comment: @Louis: Yes I have, and it was completely irrelevant. Have you found it relevant?

Comment: Okay, so I wouldn't necessarily say it is being evaluated in the traditional sense.  `Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {1}, 1, 2, 1]]` seems to evaluate the `SeriesData`, but the `t+O[t]^2` is just another representation of `SeriesData[t, 0, {1}, 1, 2, 1]`.  Try `Function[t, Plus[3, x]]` to see another example.  What I do find odd is that `Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {}, 1, 2, 1]]` gives no error, while `Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 1, 2, 1]]` does give the error.

Comment: (continued), but both of those `SeriesData` expressions have the same `InputForm`, that is `InputForm[SeriesData[t, 0, {}, 1, 2, 1]] ===
  InputForm[SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 1, 2, 1]]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius - but `Hold@SeriesData[t, 0, {}, 0, 1, 1]` does not give the error.  Something about the internal representation of `SeriesData` when the coefficients are zero

Comment: I believe the more general question is why `Hold@SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1]` reports an error. The `Function[ ]` thing is holding it, hence the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a formatting issue, that I think should be reported to WRI.

Quick and dirty workaround could be something like this:

```
Unprotect[SeriesData];
SeriesData /: MakeBoxes[
    ser : SeriesData[
        x_, x0_,
        {__?(Function[Null, MiscDump`effectiveSign@HoldComplete[#] === "0", HoldAllComplete])},
        nmin_Integer, nmax_Integer, den_Integer
    ],
    fmt_
] :=
    MakeBoxes[SeriesData[x, x0, {}, nmin, nmax, den], fmt]
Protect[SeriesData];
```

Now outputting held series data doesn't result in error messages.

```
SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1] // Hold
SeriesData[t, 0, {0.}, 0, 1, 1] // Hold
SeriesData[t, 0, {0 a}, 0, 1, 1] // Hold
SeriesData[t, 0, {Print["leak"] 0}, 0, 1, 1] // Hold
SeriesData[t, 0, {0, 0., 0 a, Print["leak"] 0}, 0, 1, 1] // Hold
(* Hold[O[t]^1]  (in all cases) *)
```

---

In `Function[t, SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1]]` expression `SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1]` is not evaluated, but when this expression is outputted in the FrontEnd it is formatted.

Rules used for formatting of `SeriesData` can be found in `FormatValues[SeriesData]`. We can see there two rules: first for empty list of coefficients, second for non-empty. In second rule we can find `` DeleteCases[MiscDump`signsAndTerms, {"0", _}] `` code followed by `` First[MiscDump`signsAndTerms] ``, where `` MiscDump`signsAndTerms `` is list containing certain special representation of series terms. Above `DeleteCases` removes terms corresponding to `0` coefficients.

It seems that possibility that there will be only `0` coefficients was overlooked and in such case `` First[MiscDump`signsAndTerms] `` receives empty list which results in `First::nofirst` error.

Formatting of non-held `SeriesData` expression with zero-only coefficients does not result in error, because such expression evaluates to `SeriesData` with empty list of coefficients which is covered by first formatting rule.

```
SeriesData[t, 0, {0}, 0, 1, 1] // InputForm
(* SeriesData[t, 0, {}, 1, 1, 1] *)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It's funny that I've only been seriously coding in Mathematica for a week or so and I've run into bugs already.

Comment: Perhaps this question should have the `bugs` tag; what does everyone think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree.

Comment: An easy bug to fix.  One comment: it would be better to write {0 ..} instead of  {(zero_ /; zero == 0) ..}.  The latter allows the arguments to evaluate (which may have bad consequences--onsider {Print[foo}), and its much slower.

Comment: One other minor point: Series would never produce a list only containing zeroes--the canonical form is an empty list--which is probably how this bug snuck through.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Thanks for pointing out evaluation leak. `{0..}` misses non-exact zeros. I guess "proper" workaround is to use the same conditions as used in functions leading to bug, so comparing ``MiscDump`effectiveSign`` to `"0"` as in edited answer.

Comment: Another refinement: you don't need `Repeated`, i.e. `_?test ..`, as `__?test` will do the same thing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, changed.